# Openssl DLLs dependency

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm currently programming server-client App using C++ and openssl. Is there anyway to hide ssleay and libeay dlls inside program codes or not use these dlls?

this means ,i dont want use these libraries and still able to use bio and other ssl features.

can i change ssl codes so that it no more need exernal library?

Comment: It seems what you are looking for is linking an external library statically. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library That means the actual library is compiled into your application. This with a combination of hiding your symbols should hide the most from the outside that these libraries are part of your application.

Comment: @alex he is not being funny, but trying to help, some respect please, what you are looking for is static library compilation, if you need SSL you need to use it and compile it inside your program, you can't just use a feature from it without really using it .